# Is it possible to exclude an element from kendo ui transformation?

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to exclude an html-element from getting transformed to a kendo ui widget.

Is this possible? Maybe via css class or so?

**Example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/8L4zg92x/

```
<input type="file" class="first"> // => KendoUpload
<input type="file" class="second"> // => plain Html-File-Upload
```

--
i'm not able to change the jquery selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("input[type=file]").kendoUpload();
);
```

Comment: None of these elements will be "transformed" unless you initiate it. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt so it is clear what you are doing and what is happening.

Comment: @CarstenFranke you are right. I've created a jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/8L4zg92x/

Comment: You cannot change the jQuery selector? If that's true, you are screwed. If you can change it, I suggest to give the elements an id and use it in the selector, e.g. `$("#upload").kendoUpload();`

Comment: @CarstenFranke that's my problem. I was hoping that there is maybe another solution.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is a different approach which might not be practical in your situation, but using declarative initialization, instead of imperative (jQuery) initialization would give you what you want:

```
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <input type="file" class="first" data-role="upload">
        <input type="file" class="second">
    </div>
    <script>
        kendo.init($("#outer"));
    </script>
</body>
```

See [Initializing with MVVM](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/mvvm-initialization) for more information on using this approach.

**Example**: https://dojo.telerik.com/eLOWaluL

Comment: thisseems to be  a very good solution for those who have access to the initialisation step.

Comment: It also works seamlessly with the [SPA framework](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/spa/overview.html), which performs this step automatically when you render a View (it will also Bind your markup to a view-model, if you've associated one with the View).

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone has the same problem, but can edit the selector. Here is an easy way to don't select the second input-field:

```
$(function() {
   $("input[type=file]:not('.second')").kendoUpload();
});
```